# C - Problems with calling multiple fork() calls

Tags: c, fork, parent-child

I have a general question about the C `fork()` operation.

If in a program, you have two separate methods that call fork(creating two children), would that cause any complications with the first call to `fork()`?

As in, trying to process the first `fork()` parameters in the second one?

I am quite new to this concept in C, any explanations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are "`fork()` parameters"? `fork()` takes no arguments.

Comment: Slightly off-topic - `fork` is not a `C` language-related thing. It's more of a `unix` or more generally OS-related feature.

Answer (score 0):

Each child created by the parent with the fork() system call is a separate process with some resources shared or inherited from the parent, thereby as a separate entity the child would not cause any complication if you try to manipulate any data.